# Update Custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a custom list view in which I show name,date and time for each list item. 
I have an Adapter which extends BaseAdapter.
I want to update this whenever the data in my database changes.
Here is my code :

```
public class UpcomingReminders extends Activity {

private Button addReminderButton;
public static DataHelper dh;
private ListView lv;
private DataSetObserver observer;
private EfficientAdapter adapter;
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Observer {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String date;
    private String time;

            //This list has the data to be shown in the listview
    private List <Reminder> upcomingReminders;

            //not sure how to use these    
    private final DataSetObservable mDataSetObservable = new DataSetObservable();

     public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
          mDataSetObservable.registerObserver(observer);
   }
     public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
         mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
    }

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
                //This will populate the list to be shown
        upcomingReminders = dh.selectAllUpcoming();
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);   
    }       
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return upcomingReminders.size();
    }       
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.upcominglistview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.reminderName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameUpcoming);
            holder.reminderDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateUpcoming);
            holder.addedBy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.AddedByUpcoming);
            holder.reminderTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeUpcoming);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
             } 
        else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }   

        String str = upcomingReminders.get(position).getReminderName();
        holder.reminderName.setText(str);
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        d = upcomingReminders.get(position).getReminderDateAndTime();
        date = ""+d.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+d.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        holder.reminderDate.setText(date);
        time = ""+d.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+d.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        holder.reminderTime.setText(time);


        holder.reminderName.setOnClickListener(new textViewClickListener(position));
        holder.reminderDate.setOnClickListener(new textViewClickListener(position));

        return convertView;
    }
    class textViewClickListener implements OnClickListener {
           int posit;
            public textViewClickListener( int pos)
                {
                    this.posit = pos;
                }
            public void onClick(View v) {
              {// you can write the code what happens for the that click and 
               // you will get the selected row index in position
                  Bundle b = new Bundle();
                  b.putString("title", upcomingReminders.get(posit).getReminderName());
                  b.putString("date", date);
                  b.putString("time", time);


                  try {
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                      Context ctx = v.getContext();
                      myIntent.setClass(ctx, ListItemDetails.class);
                      myIntent.putExtras(b);
                      ctx.startActivity(myIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.d("Activity call error:%s",e.getMessage());
                }
             }
            }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView reminderName;
        TextView reminderDate;  
        TextView reminderTime;
        TextView addedBy;
    }
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.dh = new DataHelper(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.upcoming);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //---------------------------------------
        this.addReminderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        this.addReminderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent i = new Intent();
              i.setClass(v.getContext(),AddReminderInfo.class);
              startActivity(i);
            }
          });
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(Globals.isReminderOK){
            Globals.isReminderOK = false;
            Log.i("ReminderID",""+Globals.reminderID);
            dh.updateRow(Globals.reminderID,1);
            dh.selectAllUpcoming();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } 
 }
```

After making some changes, I update the db using dh.upDateRow. This will delete a row which is currently shown in the list.
How can I update the listview to show this change?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pls share the solution of your problem ..

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your solution as I got stuck in same situation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: yeah..in the onResume function I have called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: That's not really going to help; onResume() is only called when your app comes back from the background (essentially), so if you're modifying data inside your activity, you have too call notifyDataSetChanged() when that happens.